# Permission to use the camera

Tags: java, android

Why does the application not ask for permission to use the camera during installation?

Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: post your manifest

Comment: if your device is Marshmallow and Above then runtimepermissions are applicable there

Comment: read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add also this one:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

If your application tags images with GPS location information, you must request the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.